# Rails 4 - Input User data into Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a marketplace app where sellers can list items to sell. I use devise for authentication and also have user routes to collect user inputs after they sign up.

I'm trying to set this form up to collect two seller profile inputs from users and save it in the user model. But the controller does not read the user I get an error `param not found: user` error.

my routes: the match line was added for the profile form I'm posting about.

```
  devise_for :users

  resources :users, only: [:update, :edit]

  match "/users/:id/sellerprofile", to: "users#sellerprofile", via: [:get, :put], as: :sellerprofile
```

my user controller method: note that I'm using the update process for a different form so I don't think I can use it for this form.

```
def sellerprofile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
   # if params[:user]
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update(user_params)
           format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        end
      end
    #end
end

 def update
    @user.attributes = user_params
    Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
      token = params[:stripeToken]

      recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
        :name => user_params["bankaccname"], #if i want to save to db, use this: @user.bankaccname. not saving it                 
        :type => "individual",              #gives you only one set of error messages. i don't need the respond
        :bank_account => token              #to block either i think. eg. when i enter firstname only, i get two error
        )                                   #msgs

      @user.recipient = recipient.id

     respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_url, notice: 'Your account was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:bankaccname, :profileimage, :profilestory)
  end
```

sellerprofile.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, url: sellerprofile_path(@user), html: { method: :put, :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :your_story %><i> (required)</i>
    <%= f.text_area :profilestory, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :profile_image %><i> (required)</i>
    <%= f.file_field :profileimage, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>
   </div>

 <% end %>
```

user.rb:

```
has_attached_file :profileimage, 
                  :styles => { :profile => "200x200", :p_thumb => "100x100>" },
                  :default_url => ""
validates_attachment_content_type :profileimage, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

First things first:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users

resources :users, only: [:update, :edit] do
  match :sellerprofile, via: [:get, :put], as: :sellerprofile
end
```

This is a much cleaner way to handle the route.

--

**Controller**

Next, you need to handle the data-processing capability of the controller. To do this, you need to make sure you're sending the right params (which I believe you are. If you aren't it will be in the `url`) of the form:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: sellerprofile_path, method: :put, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

You may wish to observe this routing structure inside Rails:

[image]

This is the standard routing structure inside Rails (called from the `resources` directive). This means that if you want to use a route equivalent to `update`, you will likely be able to omit the `@user` variable from it (although I've not tested this)

-

In order to make this work as correctly as you need, you need to ensure you're passing the parameters as follows:

```
params => {
  "user" => {
     "id" => "1",
     "other" => "value", 
  }
```

This will be handled by the [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) method. When you call the `user_params` in your controller, the `params.require` block looks out for the `user` param; the `permit` block looking for the individual values contained within it.

This will allow you to do the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def UsersController < ApplicationController
   def sellerprofile
      @user = User.find params[:id]
      @user.update user_params
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end
```

This should work as you need

--

**Update**

Personally, I don't see the difference between what you're doing here, and with the `update` method?

If you want to use `Stripe` details in the `update` method, why not just have a separate method for the stripe processing, and call it if you have certain params set:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user.attributes = user_params
    Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    if token. present?
      recipient = stripe
      @user.recipient = recipient.id
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update user_params
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_url, notice: 'Your account was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
  end

  private

  def stripe
     return Stripe::Recipient.create(
        :name => user_params["bankaccname"], #if i want to save to db, use this: @user.bankaccname. not saving it                 
        :type => "individual",              #gives you only one set of error messages. i don't need the respond
        :bank_account => token              #to block either i think. eg. when i enter firstname only, i get two error
        )     
  end

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:x, :y, :z)
  end
end
```

Comment: Couple questions - 1) when I change the route per your suggestion, I get a `Couldn't find User without an ID` error. 2) If I use the controller code under the Update section in your response, would I need to change the sellerprofile method? You answered my related question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657969/rails-4-updating-model-via-multiple-forms/25661012#25661012