# Rails 4 - Updating model via multiple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a process question on updating model values for an existing record. Say I have a user model. Users sign up with a name and email via devise authentication. Then I have two more forms on the site to collect additional inputs.

Form 1 stores payment data and uses the def update method. Let's say the update method has some stripe code.

Form 2 just asks for a users favorite color and wants it saved into the model. Can form 2 still use the update method with some if statement or do we need a custom route pointing to a method like def color.

I'm having trouble updating a model using form 2. And instead of posting details (done that. no solution yet) I wanted some idea on what the best process would be. It should be pretty simple to insert data into a model. I think I'm missing something basic.

Comment: You can use multi step form for this https://github.com/schneems/wicked . This consists all the detail how to build multistep form also having railscast for this so you can easily implement it.

Comment: i dont think I want a multistep form. That would be one form on multiple pages right? I want multiple seperate forms.

Comment: You have to respect CURL methods. If the 2 forms will update a model `A`, you will use the `AsController.update` method for the 2 forms. The only `if` statement you can add is to redirect into different pages after update process, passing an information into a hidden field of your form. If the 2 forms update 2 differents models `A` and `B`, then respectively use `AsController.update` and `BsController.update` methods.

Answer (score 1):

> Can form 2 still use the update method

Yes

---

**Ajax**

What you'll be looking for is ajax - [Asynchronous Javascript & XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) - a method of sending requests to your Rails server *out of scope* of your typical HTTP flow.

You have to remember Rails, by virtue of being built on HTTP, is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). This means that it has absolutely no "memory" unless, of course, you store data for future use.

The reason this is important is because when you send your "update" requests to your backend, it won't care if you've already sent a request; it will just take the data you send & blindly perform the tasks it wants:

```
#view
<%= form_for @user, method: :patch, remote: true, id: "form1" do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :color %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @user, method :patch, remote: true, id: "form2" do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :other_input %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You can [read up more about Rails UJS here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs) - both forms send the request to the `update` method, and will send different data. This will give you the ability to send the required data you need through two separate forms

--

**Response**

If you wanted to then capture the response from the forms, you'll be able to create the following Javascript:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#form1", function(status, data, xhr){
   // something here
});
```